# Full Text Search using Indexing

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, full-text-indexing

Can i create a full-text Search index on Non unique column having duplicate values?

We have sql query in which we need to get distinct records based on LIKE operator and we have approx 20 million data in a table and our requirement is get final output with concatenation

Comment: Have you tried to use the elastic-search for performing full-text search highly optimized for your use case rather than working with SQL.